# kapua , Kura client is not authorized to write to: topic://VirtualTopic.hahaha.kapua

Tags: kura, kapua

When the kura published to localhost:1883 on Kapua, I got the following errors:

> WARN o.e.k.b.c.p.KapuaSecurityBrokerFilter - User 1:kapua-broker
>   (kapua-broker - tcp://10.0.2.2:56178 - conn id is not authorized to
>   write to: topic://VirtualTopic.hahaha.kapua
>   1840321435420579455)-broker.DHT11Sensor.DHT11Data 13:26:43.493
>   [ActiveMQ NIO Worker 5] WARN o.a.a.b.TransportConnection.Service -
>   Security Error occurred on connection to: tcp://10.0.2.2:56178, User
>   1:kapua-broker (kapua-broker - tcp://10.0.2.2:56178 - conn id
>   1840321435420579455) is not authorized to write to:
>   topic://VirtualTopic.hahaha.kapua-broker.DHT11Sensor.DHT11Data
>   13:26:43.493 [ActiveMQ NIO Worker 5] WARN
>   o.a.a.t.mqtt.MQTTProtocolConverter - Failed to send MQTT Publish:
>   13:26:48.495 [ActiveMQ NIO Worker 6] WARN
>   o.e.k.b.c.p.KapuaSecurityBrokerFilter - User 1:kapua-broker
>   (kapua-broker - tcp://10.0.2.2:56178 - conn id 1840321435420579455) is
>   not authorized to write

Answer (score 2):

As I know, Kapua has a ACL access rules that define who can publis / subscribe / admin different topics/channels on broker.
If you connected to Kapua with user that has broker privileges, than you could write only to topic:
topic://VirtualTopic.{account-name}.{client-id}
now in you case that would mean that you have account hahaha and client with id kapua-broker. Is that the case? If not set the topic accordingly.
For example to something like this:
topic://VirtualTopic.kapua-sys.client-1.DHT11Sensor.DHT11Data
and when you connect wiht kapua-broker user specify client-1 as client id. Kapua-broker user is under kapua-sys account (that is a bit confusing as kapua-sys is als
o a user).
Does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment @uros-mesaric question. Its answer is correct.
Below there is just a clarification

In Kapua you are allowed to publish/subscribe according to your user permission.

If your user has only `broker:connect` permission you can publish/subscribe only on topic:

```
{account-name}/{connectionClientId}/{semanticTopic}
```

In your specific case you should publish/subscribe on topic:

```
kapus-sys/1840321435420579455/DHT11Sensor/DHT11Data
```

`kapua-sys` is the account name to which the user kapua-broker belongs,
 while `1840321435420579455` is the clientId used to create the connection.

Please note that username used to connect and account name are two different things in Kapua. An account has multiple users.